# How to generate a php.ini file out of current environment?

Tags: php, php-fpm, php.ini

For some of my running PHP-FPM web applications, I need to set up cronjobs. Currently they are using the CLI default `php.ini`.

Is there an easy way (e.g. script) to generate a new `php.ini` from the current environment?

I want to use those autogenerated `php.ini` files within cronjobs (like `php -c /srv/foo/php.ini -f /srv/foo/cron.php`)

Of course, I could do it by hand, copy the FPM default config and manually replace the overwritten values with the one's setup with the PHP-FPM pool configuration but that result in some weeks of copy&pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write out a dynamic php.ini by running something like

```
<?php 
$s = array();
foreach(ini_get_all() as $k=>$v) {
     if ($v['local_value'] || $v['global_value']) {
        $s[] = sprintf("%s = %s", $k, $v['local_value']?$v['local_value']:$v['global_value']);
    }
}

file_put_contents("out.ini", join("\n", $s));
?>
```